# Boto - How to edit a record type

Tags: python, boto, amazon-route53

I've a little question: is there a way to edit the record type, for example, from an **A** record to a **CNAME** record without delete and re-create the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route 53 does not have an edit option.  You can do a DELETE/CREATE in the same batch[1] and its considered a transaction.  So if delete fails, the change won't be applied.

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html